# Django Wagtail CSV and photo "upload" - management command

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, wagtail, django-2.0

I am working on a django/wagtail management command (let's call it "file_upload") that does roughly the following:

- take "csv" argument, which is a full path to a CSV file.
- parse and open the result using `csv`
- for each row, create and save a custom Wagtail Image model object (inheriting from `AbstractImage`, with a few extra `CharField` that I do not think prevent me from doing what I want to do)

The (currently simplified) CSV looks like this:

```
1.jpg,Title 1
2.jpg,Title 2
```

Does not complicated at all, even straightforward ... but this Wagtail aspect of things does not seem to be heavily documented. The following does not work:

```
import csv
import argparse
import os, sys

from django.core.files import File
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings

from custom_photo.models import CustomPhoto


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--csv', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'))

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(options['csv'].name))
        with options['csv'] as csvfile:
            readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in readCSV:
                # the file full path assumes everything is flat in the same folder
                with open('%s/%s' %(path, row[0]), 'rb') as f:
                    django_file = File(open)
                    print(django_file)
                    photo = CustomPhoto()
                    photo.title=row[1]
                    # three arguments:
                    # 1) relative path inside MEDIA_ROOT
                    # 2) the django File object
                    # 3) Whether or not we want to save the photo object after the image is saved
                    photo.file.save(row[0], django_file, True)
                    print(photo.__dict__)
```

is run like this:

```
python manage.py cca_photo_import --csv=C:\path\to\file\list.csv
```

And throw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "<snip>env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "<snip>env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "<snip>env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "<snip>env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "<snip>cca\cca_photo\management\commands\cca_photo_import.py", line 43, in handle
    photo.file.save(row[0], django_file, True)
  File "<snip>env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 87, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "<snip>env\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 49, in save
    return self._save(name, content)
  File "<snip>env\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 268, in _save
    for chunk in content.chunks():
  File "<snip>env\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\base.py", line 71, in chunks
    data = self.read(chunk_size)
  File "<snip>env\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\utils.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    read = property(lambda self: self.file.read)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Many thanks

Comment: `File(open)` looks wrong. Should that be `File(f)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **gasman**, this is now working. Duh.

```
import csv
import argparse
import os, sys

from django.core.files import File
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings

from custom_photo.models import CustomPhoto, CustomPhotoPlate, CustomPhotoType


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--csv', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'))

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(options['csv'].name))
        with options['csv'] as csvfile:
            readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in readCSV:
                photo_path = '%s/%s' %(path, row[0])
                with open(photo_path, 'rb') as f:
                    django_file = File(f)
                    photo = CustomPhoto()
                    photo.title=row[1]
                    photo.file = django_file
                    photo.save()
                    print(photo.__dict__)
```

The `photo` object is saved, etc, etc. All good.

However, the `file` field for that object is now populated with:

```
original_images/CFolderSubFolderSubSubFolderSubSubSubFolder1.jpg
```

Where CFolderSubFolderSubSubFolderSubSubSubFolder is apparently the cleaned version of `C:\Folder\SubFolder\SubSubFolder\SubSubSubFolder`

Any way to get rid of this (useless) path? Which is apparently the full path to the JPG file.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is: `django_file = File(f, name=row[0])`