# Importing / bulk creating pages in Django / Wagtail

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail

Wagtail and Django are very efficient and sophisticated frameworks, but they do not offer any simple way of importing (i.e bulk creating) pages. I have tried dozens of suggestions to do so ([eg 1](https://medium.com/@kevinhowbrook/migrating-your-drupal-content-to-wagtail-d43bb34529e8), [eg 2](https://github.com/outdoorsy/wagtail-csv-import), [eg 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63181320/bulk-uploading-and-creating-pages-with-images-in-wagtail-migration), [eg 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040023/programatically-add-a-page-to-a-known-parent), etc). I've also tried CodeRedCMS (which is based on Wagtail), but it offers a very rudimentary function and I do not want to add additional dependencies. Gazmans solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040023/programatically-add-a-page-to-a-known-parent) seemed very efficient but I could not figure out exactly how to go about solving the issue.

So my question is simple: **If I have a csv/json file with thousands of rows, where each row represents a post for a specific Page Model I've created in Wagtail, how do I import it to Wagtail?** Any example with psuedo code would be immensely appreciated.

The solutions that I almost succeed with were by (1) either using DataGrip and directly import data into the table, or (2) using the **loaddata** management command in Django. However, both these methods resulted in Wagtail not registering the entries, such that I could verify that they existed in the database table but not in the parent table and not visible in the admin backend, which I believe is due to *multi-table inheritance*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recipe which should point you in the right direction:

https://gist.github.com/tomdyson/ef8c2f684620b84feaddfd7454e09647

This shows the creation of an example `Film` page model for Wagtail, along with a management command which creates ~35k pages from a downloaded CSV file.

You could also check out my [wagtail-fakenews](https://github.com/tomdyson/wagtail-fakenews) app, which generates Wagtail pages with dummy content. It doesn't import from CSV, but it does include images and StreamField content (see [make_fake_items.py](https://github.com/tomdyson/wagtail-fakenews/blob/master/fakenews/management/commands/make_fake_items.py)), which the first recipe doesn't.

Comment: Grateful for that very clear and efficient example. Worked like a charm to read 50k rows.